# How to combine 2 arrays in a single one

Tags: c, arrays

As a programming newbie I have a question for you people,

For not any specific purpose, I wonder if I take 2 arrays from user, than I put them together in a single seperate array, how can I avoid taking the 2 of the same characters in the latter array?

To clarify, let's say that user entered "sea" and "blue" as 2 seperate arrays,

How can I put them together in a single array like "s,e,a,b,l,u" instead of "s,e,a,b,l,u,e" in C programming language?

Comment: Show what have you tried?

Comment: read something about `nested for loops`. Those may be the key to your solution.

Comment: Seems like homework, as well as your other question(s).

Comment: It actually is not a homework, as you can see I didn't want anything specific or a source code, a pseudo code or something like that works for me, cause I just couldn't think of an idea

Comment: You can use `strchr` to check whether the character is present in the result array before adding it. (Don't forget that strchr expects a null-terminated string.)

Comment: @Kaupp this is the right place to ask homework related questions (concerning computer programming), as long as you don't expect people to do the work for you and I'm not saying your question is homework.

Comment: @Kaupp This is the right place to ask homework related questions and expect people to do the work. Trust me.:)

Comment: `"sea" and "blue"` => `"seablu"`, So `"blue" and "sea"` => ?? `"blusea"` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY more like "bluesa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have not to separate characters in the destination array with commas.

Here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s1[] = "sea";
    char s2[] = "blue";
    char s3[sizeof( s1 ) + sizeof( s2 ) - 1];
    char *p, *q;

    strcpy( s3, s1 );
    p = s3 + strlen( s1 );

    for ( q = s2; *q; ++q )
    {
        if ( strchr( s1, *q ) == NULL )
        {
            *p++ = *q;
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );
    puts( s3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
sea
blue
seablu
```

Or if you want the destination array could have unique characters of the two (or more) source arrays then the code can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "sea";
    char s2[] = "blue";
    const char * a[] = { s1, s2 };
    char s3[sizeof( s1 ) + sizeof( s2 ) - 1];
    size_t i;
    char *p, *q;

    p = s3;

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        const char *q = a[i];
        for ( ; *q; ++q )
        {
            char *t = s3;

            while ( t != p && *t != *q ) ++t;
            if ( t == p )
            {
                *p++ = *q;
            }
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );
    puts( s3 );

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above.

Take into account that if you will initialize the destination array with zeroes like

```
char s3[sizeof( s1 ) + sizeof( s2 ) - 1] = { '\0' };
```

then instead of loop

```
while ( t != p && *t != *q ) ++t;
```

you can use function `strchr` the same way as in the first demonstrative program.

Comment: This will not prevent characters from appearing twice. If `sea` would be `seea`, then there would still be two `e`s. Anyway, good answer, I don't get the down-vote without feedback.

Comment: @Benno Zeeman  Read one more the original post. There is nothing said about duplicates in the first array. And before you are going to down vote some answer please be caution.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, I up-voted. I interpreted "how can I avoid taking the 2 of the same characters in the latter array" wrongly, apparently. Sorry.

Comment: @Benno Zeeman His question can be interpretated differently: either as unique characters of two arrays or as appended characters of the second array shall not be duplicated relative to the first array. So I think he will say himself whether it is what he is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that :

```
int is_in_array(char *str, char c)
{
  int i;
  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (str[i] == c)
        return 1;
      i++
    }
  return 0;
}

int arraySize(char *str)
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0')
    i++;
  return i;
}
int add_array(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int size;
  char *str_all;

  size = arraySize(str1) + arraySize(str2);
  str_all = malloc(size * sizeof(str_all*));
  while (str1[i] != '\0')
    {
      str_all[i] = str1[i];
      i++;
    }
  j = 0;
  while (str2[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (is_in_array(str1, str2[j]) == 0)
        {
          str_all[i] = str2[j];
          i++;
        }
      j++;
    }
}
```